# How to stop the multithreaded process by ctrl+c

Tags: multithreading, python-2.7

I'm trying to kill the process during executing, but it failed to stop it.

My thread is infinite loop thread won't be terminated until received kill signal

[image]

I can only terminated by kill command on terminal

```
def signal_handler(*args):
    print("Killed by user")
    teardown()
    sys.exit(0)

def install_signal():
    for sig in (SIGABRT, SIGILL, SIGINT, SIGSEGV, SIGTERM):
        signal(sig, signal_handler)


class Monitor(object):
    ...
    def run(self):
        """Run the monitor thread

        Add the tasks to threads list
        """
        try:
            threads = {
                "streaming": Streaming(
                    self.args["rtsp_link"], 
                    int(self.args["duration"]), 
                    int(self.args["period"])
                ),
                "telnet_vid": p,
                "telnet_aud": c,
            }

            for sub_task in threads.values():
                sub_task.setDaemon(True)
                sub_task.start()

            for sub_task in threads.values():
                sub_task.join()

            time.sleep(1)

            logging.info("Completed Monitor Tasks")

        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            print("Ok ok, quitting")
            sys.exit(1)
        except BaseException as e:
            print("Got BaseException")
            traceback.print_exc(file=sys.stdout)
            raise e

def main():
    try:
        install_signal()
        monitor = Monitor('tests/test_configuration.txt')
        monitor.run()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("Ok ok, quitting")
        sys.exit(1)
```

If I add timeout to `join()` the main thread won't be blocked will terminated in few seconds and can not received keyboard interrupt anymore

I referred to this [blog](http://www.regexprn.com/2010/05/killing-multithreaded-python-programs.html)

```
while len(running_threads) > 0 :
    try:
        print("To add join")
        # Join all threads using a timeout so it doesn't block
        # Filter out threads which have been joined or are None
        running_threads = [t.join(1) for t in running_threads if t is not None and t.isAlive()]
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("Ctrl+C received! Sending kill to threads!!!")
        for t in running_threads:
            t.kill_received = True
```

Comment: add `timeout` to `sub_task.join()` and call `is_alive()` to find out whether a thread is ended. On Python 2, `thread.join()` without a timeout might be uninterruptible by a signal.

Comment: Hi @J.F.Sebastian I updated the post, it doesn't work

Comment: `t.join(1)` always returns `None` therefore `running_threads = [t.join(1) for ...]` is incorrect

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian why? you said add an `timeout` to join, so I added `1` sec for the join.

Comment: ponder why `running_threads = [None, None, None, ...]` is not terribly useful

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian My thread is infinite loop thread won't be terminated until received kill signal

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
for sub_task in threads.values():
    sub_task.join() # no timeout
```

with:

```
running_threads = threads.values()
while running_threads:
    for t in running_threads:
        t.join(.1) # with timeout
    running_threads = [t for t in running_threads if t.is_alive()]
```